# return array of objects by foreign key from database table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I have a database it looks like this:

Entity: Post, Comment.. Comment has a foreign key post_id.

I need to get Comments that belongs to specific post by its ID. And sort it by getCreated() metod.

Problem is, when i try to find all comments by post_id like:

```
$comments = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('BlogCommonBundle:Comment')->findBypost_id($postID); 

usort($comments, function($a, $b){
       return ($a->getCreated() < $b->getCreated());
    });
```

Im gettig `..CommonBundle\Entity\Comment' has no field 'postId'.`
Probably because its foreign key.

Is there any way, how to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could try `findBy(array('IDENTITY(comment)' => $postID))`, although I'm not sure if you can use the IDENTITY function within findBy...so you might need to create a query builder instead.

Comment: thanks but, it gives "Unrecognized field: IDENTITY(Comment)" :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have an association like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post")
 */
protected $post;
```

So you should find your comments by `post`, not by `post_id`:

```
$comments = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('BlogCommonBundle:Comment')->findBy(['post' => $postID]);
```

And you can also sort it just by adding `['created' => 'DESC']` as a second parameter:

```
$comments = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('BlogCommonBundle:Comment')->findBy(['post' => $postID], ['created' => 'DESC']);
```